# arccotg(cotg(f)) - inverse function

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I know that arccotg(cotg(f)) = f, but what if there is a number inside the arccotg function? Example: arccotg(2cotg(f)) = ? or any other number inside the arccotg function?

Comment: To begin with, $\mathrm{arccotg}(\mathrm{cotg}(f)) \ne f$ in general.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut lol I studied that in university

Comment: It cannot be correct, compare range on Left and Right side.

Comment: @samjoe (0, π) is the range

Comment: You may have learned that $\mathrm{cotg}(\mathrm{arccotg}(f))=f$, which is true for all real $f$, but what you write is wrong, unless $f$ is constrained to stay in $]0,\pi[$. Also, while you can simplify $\mathrm{cotg}(n\,\mathrm{arccotg}(f))=f$ as a rational function of $f$, for all $n$, you can't do that with $\mathrm{arccotg}(\mathrm{n\,cotg}(f))=f$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and what if it's cotg(2arccotg(f))?

Comment: Then use the addition formula $\mathrm{cotg}(x+y)=\dfrac{\mathrm{cotg}(x)\mathrm{cotg}(y)-1}{\mathrm{cotg}(x)+\mathrm{cotg}(y)}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and if it's arccotg(2cot(f))?